# 了 with verbs like 不要，该，得

Tags: grammar

I wonder what's the purpose of 了 in combination of "must, have to" verbs. Here are some examples:

1. 我得把今天的练习做了。
   I know without 了 it would mean "I must do today's exercises".
   But I don't know what changes does the particle 了 bring here? Is this 了1 or 了2?
2. 我该回去了。
   Without 了 it would mean "I must return". But I don't know how to translate this sentence with 了.
3. 您不要出来了。
   Without 了 it would mean "You shouldn't come out". What's the difference between the sentence above with "您不要出来".

Comment: 不要 = don't; 该 = should; 得 = have to; 了 can be a particle that indicates the verb is completed  but it is a final particle in these sentences

Answer (score 1):

The word 了 usually doesn't change the meaning of the text.

**1. The word 了 is often used after verbs and adjectives to mean that something has finished. 2. Also used at the end of a sentence or a stop which means that something will or has already changed**

Examples:

1. (1) 我吃完饭了 —— I am done eating （吃 is a verb and it means something has finished）
2. (1) 水位已经降了两米 —— The water level has been lowered by two meters （降 is a verb）
3. (2) 春天要来了——Spring is coming (The season will change soon)
4. (2) 天黑了——It's dark already (already changed)

Answer (score 1):

When at the end of a sentence, 了 has two functions/meanings:

1. to indicate a change of state - something has been completed. 長大了, 變老了, 水位降低了...
2. to inform the beginning of an action.

- 我得把今天的练习做了。(I must start to do today's homework)
- 我该回去了。(I shall go home now)
- 您不要出来了 = 您不要出来 (You do not need to come out), the former way is more polite. Also 您不**用**出来 is often used too.
- 